# react native datepicker works only in debug mode

Tags: react-native

I'm using [native datepicker of android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/datepickerandroid.html) in react native app , only when I use debug mode I get date, but when I cancel debug mode using real phone I get in alert **'invalid date'** in same date I choose with the debug.

```
  showDatePicker = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        this.setState({ datePickerIosPlatform: true })
    } else {
        try {
            const { action, year, month, day } = await DatePickerAndroid.open({
                date: new Date()
            });
            if (action !== DatePickerAndroid.dismissedAction) {
               console.log('action', action, 'year', year, ' month', month, 'day', day)

                var stringDate = `${year} ${month} ${day}`;
                var newDate = new Date(stringDate)
                alert(newDate)

                var convertDate = moment(newDate).format('DD.MM.YYYY') 
                console.log('convertdata',convertDate)

                // this.convertDate(stringDate)
            }
        } catch ({ code, message }) {
            console.warn('Cannot open date picker', message);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you can change this string `${year} ${month} ${day}` to `${year}/${month}/${day}` so it will not say 'invalid date' again

Comment: thanks. it solve my issue, why in my way it's not works?

Comment: I think for android when the format doesn't have dash or slash it doesn't work. However, when the format is set to "YY-MM-DD" or  "YY/MM/DD", it will work.

Comment: okay fine. good to know. thanks for your time

Comment: could you please help me with this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967235/react-native-moment-not-working-for-specific-time-value-without-debug-mode

Answer (score 0):

Today I had a similar issue **(and solved it!)**.

I've tried to generate an Date-Object of an given String (German Date Format) `new Date("06.06.2020")`. After that, I've tried to compare the generated Date with today `new Date()`.

As it worked well on Debug-Mode, it doesn't work on a bundled Release APK. I got `invalid Date`-Message even like you.

**Solution**

I've figured out, that you must have an full qualified [ISO_8601](http://%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted string to generate an date.

So I did the following to convert my date in that ISO_8601 formatted:

```
const startNextFestival = "06.10.2020".split('.').reverse().join('-')+"T10:00:00.000Z";
const nextFestival = new Date(startNextFestival);
```

This generates following Date-String for startNextFestival: "2020-06-06T10:00:00.000Z"
This way it works like a charm, to generate.

Hope that's helps somebody.