# Getting "INVALID DATE" if device or emulator not in "debug remotely" mode

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I'm building chat fonctionality in an app and i'm using FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat. When i debug on chrome the messages dates are good.
if i'm not debugging remotely all dates of messages become "INVALID DATE".
I have same result on real device and emulator

I format date i get from the API to the format the library is in using this function:

```
formatOneMessage(message) {
  const receiver = this.props.navigation.getParam("receiver");
  const receiverName = receiver.Name;
  const receiverLastName = receiver.lastName;
  const formatedDate = Util.formatDate(message.creation_date)
  const FormatedMessage = {
    _id: message.id,
    text: message.content,
    createdAt: new Date(formatedDate),
    user: {
      _id: message.sender_id,
      name: receiverName + " " + receiverLastName,
      avatar: "https://placeimg.com/140/140/any"
    }
  };
  return FormatedMessage;
}
```

```
formatDate(date){
  let dateAndTimeArray = date.split(" ");
  let dateArray = dateAndTimeArray[0].split("-");
  let newDate = dateArray[1] + "-" + dateArray[0] + "-" + dateArray[2];
  let newDateAndTime = newDate + " " + dateAndTimeArray[1]
  return newDateAndTime;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i used moment.js to resolve this issue:

```js
 formatOneMessage(message) {
    const receiverName = this.props.navigation.getParam("receiverName");
    const modifiedDate = Util.formatDate(message.creation_date);
    const formatedDate = moment(modifiedDate, "MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss");

    const FormatedMessage = {
      _id: message.id,
      text: message.content,
      createdAt: formatedDate,
      user: {
        _id: message.sender_id,
        name: receiverName,
        avatar: "https://placeimg.com/140/140/any"
      }
    };

    return FormatedMessage;
  }
```

if you are curious what `Util.formatDate` is doing:

```js
formatDate(date) {
    let dateAndTimeArray = date.split(" ");
    let dateArray = dateAndTimeArray[0].split("-");
    let newDate = dateArray[1] + "-" + dateArray[0] + "-" + dateArray[2];
    let newDateAndTime = newDate + " " + dateAndTimeArray[1];

    return newDateAndTime;
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I used Moment.JS to fix this issue myself, using the

```
moment().format()
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, that your Parameter for "new Date()" has ISO_8601 Format. 
More information about this see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58353084/1256697